# Cannot receive firebase notification in Real iOS Device but working in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, firebase

i'm new in FCM.

I develop notification Apps for Android and iOS.

I already done successful with Android push notification via Firebase but i failed in iOS.

```
What i face are :

1. iOS notification working well in iPhone 5 simulator with iOS 12
2. iOS notification not working in real device (iPhone) : nothing happen
```

> **What i have done before :**
>
> 1. Create development certificate for APNs
> 2. Upload p12 to Firebase Console
> 3. Install provision certificate for project in iPhone (real device)
> 4. Create App Id and activate APNs (configured)

After all effort above, notification still not appear in Real device , but i can sure it appear in Simulator.

By the way i create project using React Native, but i think it's not bug in Firebase library. Maybe something i missing in setting?